# Error while adding CVS repository(extssh) in ReviewBoard

Tags: version-control, cvs, review-board

I installed ReviewBoard in my local and trying to connect to remote CVS repository. While I am trying to add CVS repository in ReviewBoard, I'm seeing below error. Please help.

**The executable "cvs" is not in the path.**

I used below string to specify path,

:extssh:UserName:Password@IP:/Path/to/CVSROOT

Answer (score 0):

I suspect uou need the `cvs` command/package installed on your reviewboard server. It is either not installed, or not installed in a normal place that's in your PATH.